# Why does Fish shell have dark blue as the default color for directories

Tags: shell, colors, fish

Is it just me?

I have just installed fish using `brew install fish` and I'm using iTerm2.

[image: Fish shell dark blue]

The color is absolutely unreadable. How do I change it to something nicer?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I realized my mistake was with iTerm and not with Fish.

Press `CMD+i` with an iTerm window open, then click the `Colors` tab and set it something nicer.

[image]

Not sure why this problem didn't show up before, but it seems like it was triggered by the new Fish installation.

Comment: To make the change permanently, you need to click 'General' -> 'Copy Current Settings to Selected Profile'

Comment: I recommend choosing a better color theme by clicking on `Color Presets...` at the bottom right. I switched to `Pastel (dark background)`: much more readable in one click!

Answer (score 4):

Technically that isn't fish doing the coloring. It's the `ls` command. However, fish does wrap the command in a `ls` function which tells the command to color the output and use the colors specified by the `dircolors` command if it is installed. If you don't want the coloring you can create your own `ls` function that omits the `--color=auto` flag. Or you can define your own `$LS_COLORS` env var to keep from using the colors provided by `dircolors`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `alias ls="ls"` to your `~/.config/fish/config.fish` file.
if you don't have `config.fish` on your fish directory, create it!

This trick will change `ls` command's color to white.